# How do I get the documents that has highest _score in same keys?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on Elasticsearch. 
How do I get the documents that has highest _score in same keys? and Which API should I use or read?

*Example Documents And Query*

```js
{ "foreignId": 1, "body": "One is a green apple, however another one is red."}
{ "foreignId": 1, "body": "apple apple apple apple" } // has a higher score than the one right above
{ "foreignId": 2, "body": "One is a green apple, however another one is red."}
{ "foreignId": 2, "body": "apple apple apple" } // has a higher score than the one right above

{"query": { "match_phrase": { "body": "apple"}}}
```

*Expected*

```js
{ "foreignId": 1, "body": "apple apple apple apple", _score: <the highest where foreignId=1> }
{ "foreignId": 2, "body": "apple apple apple", _score: <the highest where foreignId=2> }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-collapse) and sort by _score

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "body": "apple"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "foreignId"
  },
  "sort": ["_score"]
}
```